# How ro run terraform from container with alias from a wsl console?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terraform

I like to use terraform without installing it localy to my system. My problem is propably a  volume or path issue.

I have two stuctures. `setup` hosts all container files for `php`, `compser`, `terraform`, etc...

and the `project` folders from where I run the alias

```
└───setup
    ├───composer
    │    Dockerfile
    │    composer.sh
    │
    ├───php
    │    Dockerfile
    │
    └───terraform
         tf.sh  

└───projectA                
    ├───modules   
    │   ├───moduleA
    │   ├───moduleb
    │   └───module..
    │ 
    ├───env
    │    terraform.tfvars
    │ 
    │ main.tf
    │ variables.tf
    │ output.tf
```

I use the `setup/terraform/tf.sh` out of an alias from the `projectA` directory

The content of my `tf.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash
docker run --rm -it --name terraform \
    -v $pwd:/workspace \
    -w /workspace hashicorp/terraform:light $@
```

When I run `tf init`, terraform is saying, I run this on an empty directory:

```
Terraform initialized in an empty directory!

The directory has no Terraform configuration files. You may begin working
with Terraform immediately by creating Terraform configuration files.
```

If I change the code in `tf.sh' from the above to:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls $pwd $@
```

and run `tf -lsah` again, I get the terraform files as expected.

```
.                
..               
main.tf          
outputs.tf       
variables.tf
```

It seems, I have a mistake somewhere in my `tf.sh` file.

Ps.:
my `~/.bash_aliases`:

```
alias tf='/setup/terraform/tf.sh'
```

## Edit

I made some progress by changing the volume mounts

```
docker run --rm -it -v "$(PWD):/data" /
  -w /data hashicorp/terraform:light init /
  -backend-config="env/backend.tfvars"
```

Even if I'm not at my coal, the error below tells me, I'm on the right path:

```
Initializing the backend...
╷
│ Error: Error building ARM Config: Please ensure you have installed Azure CLI version 2.0.79 or newer. Error parsing json result from the Azure CLI: Error launching Azure CLI: exec: "az": executable file not found in $PATH.
```

My guess is, I need to build a multi-stage container image with terraform and azure-cli. Please correct me if I'm wrong! I was hoping to find a simple way with the `hashicorp/terraform:light` image alone.

## Edit 2

I build a custom image with `terraform:light` and added `azure-cli`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli
COPY --from=hashicorp/terraform:light /bin/terraform /bin/ 
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/terraform"]
```

works fine but yeah, doesn't realy help without having an active session

```
Initializing the backend...                                                                                                                                                                                            
╷                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
│ Error: Error building ARM Config: obtain subscription() from Azure CLI: Error parsing json result from the Azure CLI: Error waiting for the Azure CLI: exit status 1: ERROR: Please run 'az login' to setup account. 
│
```

I'm wondering if what I'm trying to do is even possible that way

Comment: Running user tools designed to be ran mostly from a workstation inside of a container will always run into a lot of issues like this.

Comment: It is actually a common use case to change versions to test things under different circumstances without harming the environment. Second, all of the tools mentioned are used to build automated pipelines. I fixed everything and will post the final solution shortly. The short answer is the correct mounting in Docker and the use of SAS tokens for the azure-cli in the `terraform/azure-cli` container

Comment: IMO that problem is much better solved by `brew`, `flatpak`, `snap`, `tfenv`. There are a ton of solutions to both sandboxing and version management specifically for desktop use. That's not docker's strong point.

Comment: I'll take me some time to test other solutions but `brew` will not be helpful on linux but any packet managers would not fulfill my requirement and `tfenv` is terraform only. My goal is, to switch between stack A to stack B by simply change one or view parameters. 'flatpak' might be interesting, I don't know it yet. Anyhow, I thank you very much for investing your time and share your thoughts on this! Very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for the original question was already given in `Edit 2`. However, it results in a follow-up issue, passing authentication through the `terraform/azure-cli` container.

Here is a summery:

The goal is, to have an alias for `terraform` like `tf`, that runs terraform in a container, rather than having it installed on the local environment. Depending on the `provider`, this may have some dependencies. In my case, I require 'azurerm' and this requires `azure-cli` for the `terraform backend-config`.

Therefore, you can't simply run:

```
docker run --rm -it -v "$(pwd):/data" -w /data hashicorp/terraform:light $@
```

because `azure-cli` would missing.

Therefore, I build an image, starting from `azure-cli` and added the `terraform` binay:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/azure-cli
COPY --from=hashicorp/terraform:light /bin/terraform /bin/ 
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/terraform"]
```

**Build Image**

```
docker build -t terraform:azure-cli .
```

For the Alias, I've created bash file with the `docker run` command, including `$@` to allow  passing any arguments that terraform provides and assigned an Alias to it:

**tf.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
docker run --rm -it \
    -v "$PWD:/data" \
    -w /data terraform:azure-cli $@
```

**~/.bash_aliases**

```
alias tf='/mnt/c/Users/***/localGit/setup/terraform/tf.sh'
```

In order to use this, requires to handover authenticable backend-config data, to avoid user-interaction while azure-cli queries the 'tfstate' storage account. I solved this using short-lived `Shared Access Signature (SAS) Tokens`. So I create a local `azure.conf` file that looks like this:

```
# azure.conf, must be in .gitignore
storage_account_name="azurestorageaccountname"
container_name="storagecontainername"
key="prod.tfstate"
sas_token="?sv=2021-09-17…"
```

That is fine (especially for Development) but refreshing and copy/paste the token may not be funny. Therefore, I decided to run a script, that rotates the access-keys and generate and SAS Token as environment variable:

In order to get an SAS token as environment variable, I export them with a `backend.sh` script

**backend.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
storage_account_name=$TF_STATE_BLOB_ACCOUNT_NAME
container_name=$TF_STATE_BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME
resource_group=$TF_RESOURCE_GROUP

# Rotate and retrieve Storage Account Access Key
account_key=$(az storage account keys renew -g $resource_group -n $storage_account_name --key primary --query '[0].value' -o tsv)

# Generate SAS Token
end=$(date -u -d "1 hour" '+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%MZ')
sas=$(az storage container generate-sas --name $container_name \
  --expiry $end \
  --permissions dlrw \
  --account-name $storage_account_name \
  --account-key $account_key)

sas="${sas%\"}" && sas="${sas#\"}"

# Export Environment Variables
export ARM_ACCESS_KEY=$account_key
export ARM_SAS_TOKEN=$sas
```

Finally, I run my alias `tf` with the common Terraform Arguments as I would do it in any pipeline:

```
$ tf init \
  -backend-config="storage_account_name=$TF_STATE_BLOB_ACCOUNT_NAME" \
  -backend-config="container_name=$TF_STATE_BLOB_CONTAINER_NAME" \
  -backend-config="key=$TF_STATE_BLOB_FILE" \
  -backend-config="sas_token=$ARM_SAS_TOKEN"
```